# Discarding characters in input buffer?

Tags: java

I'm reading an intro into java book and I'm at this section involving do while loops. here is the code:

```
public class GuessingGameV4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        char ch, ignore, answer;

        answer = 'K';

        do {
            System.out.println("I am thinking of a letter between A and Z");
            System.out.println("Can you guess it?");

            ch = (char) System.in.read();

            do {
                ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while (ignore != '\n');

            if (ch == answer) System.out.println("Right!!! ");
            else {
                System.out.print("Sorry you are ");
                if (ch < answer) System.out.print("too low.\n");
                else System.out.print("too high.\n");

                System.out.println("Try again\n");
            } 
        } while (answer != ch);
    }
}
```

The inner do while loop that involves ignore is the part of the code that is discarding the characters in the input buffer.

I just want more clarifications what it's actually doing because the books explanation isn't doing it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the part that's giving you trouble:

> ```
> System.out.println("I am thinking of a letter between A and Z");
> System.out.println("Can you guess it?");
>
> ch = (char) System.in.read();
>
> do {
>     ignore = (char) System.in.read();
> } while (ignore != '\n');
> ```

The program is asking the user to enter a single letter.
But `System.in` is buffered.
The user can actually type several characters.
Even a long sentence.
Until finally he presses the Enter, which is character `'\n'`.

The program reads a character into `ch`:

> ```
> ch = (char) System.in.read();
> ```

Then it goes further, and keeps reading until it finds a `'\n'` character:

> ```
> do {
>     ignore = (char) System.in.read();
> } while (ignore != '\n');
> ```

If you don't do this step,
then any extra input the user entered will get carried over for the next iteration of the outer loop.
You don't want anything carried over,
you want just the first character entered,
discard the rest,
so that in the next iteration you start with a clean buffer.

Try the code with the loop with `ignore` commented out.
If you enter a single letter,
the outer loop will run twice,
for the letter you entered and the `'\n'` character that ended your input.
If you enter multiple letters,
let's say "hello",
the loop will run 6 times,
5 times for the letters h-e-l-l-o and one more time for the `'\n'` character that ends input.

-> The loop with `ignore` is necessary to clear the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange example.

It will say "Right!!!" to the answer:

```
Its definitely not K\n
```

As it will ignore all but the last Char in the line you enter and compare the last character to the character in the `answer` variable.

**Update:** Actually it ignores all but the first Character. Sorry. So it should be

```
K is definitely not the answer\n
```

I guess its to handle the case of a \r\n at the end of line like under windows. (Carriage return)